# Is there any proof a permissive licenced (MIT/BSD) project will suffer from closed forks?

Tags: gpl, mit-license, bsd-license

Hi is there any stats that a MIT/BSD licence project is hindered (as far as getting people to contribute) from closed forks?

Stats or resources but not opinions of which license is best please.

Note: I have updated the question to show I'm only looking for facts on contributor count or change of contributors in close fork enabled projects vs not.

I merely want to know if there are facts out there on this not what people conclude from the facts.

Comment: Look what happened to the GPL mysql at Google and Amazon. That's why AGPL exists. MongoDB is AGPL and still friendly to closed source use, but not modification.

Comment: How is this "primarily opinion-based" when it's asking for statistics? Statistics aren't opinions.

Comment: When I publish code using the MIT license (or CC0/public domain) I'm more worried about a fork using a viral license (GPL, etc.) than about a closed source fork.

Comment: The close reason is blatantly wrong, but this is essentially an off-site resource request so it should still be closed.